# innerHTML and use of Array

Tags: javascript, html

I have several div tags trainingData0, trainingData1, trainingData2, etc   that I am trying to use innerHTML to update text.

I am trying to refer to them with a for loop but it doesn't work.  (even though trainingDataDiv does hold the correct value ie trainingData0 which DOES work if I type trainingData0.innerHTML )

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="trainingData0"></div>
---------------
for (var i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        var trainingDataDiv = "trainingData" + i;
        trainingDataDiv.innerHTML = data;
    }
```

Comment: `var trainingDataDiv = document.getElementById("trainingData" + i);`

Comment: As you tagged your question with `html` you should support your question with example `html`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen works a treat thanks

Comment: your original trainingDataDiv is just a string named trainingDataDiv1, it isn't a reference to elements on the page and it doesn't have an innerHTML property.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 thanks for clarifying that for me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Robby Cornelissen in comments of my question :)

```
for (var i=0; i<15; i++)
{
    var trainingDataDiv = document.getElementById("trainingData" + i);
    trainingDataDiv.innerHTML = data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you don't have to change your max number when you change the number of elements:

```js
//Get all elelemtns with ids that start with trainingData
var trainingDataDivs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='trainingData']");
var data = "I'm training Data";

//iterate the elements we found earlier and update the data
for(var i = 0;  i < trainingDataDivs.length; i++)
{
    trainingDataDivs[i].innerHTML = data;
}
```

```html
<div id="trainingData0"></div>
<div id="trainingData1"></div>
<div id="trainingData2"></div>
<div id="trainingData3"></div>
<div id="trainingData4"></div>
<div id="trainingData8"></div><!-- Note the gap in numbers -->
<div id="bob">I'm not training</div>
```

For more info see [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)